# Standalone: Remove number from output filename

Tags: standalone

I am using the following file to convert a single-page tikz graphic to png:

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert={ghostscript}]{standalone}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikz}
    \node {Test};
\end{tikz}%
\end{document}
```

This gets compiled with `pdflatex --shell-escape --interaction=nonstopmode temp` under MikTeX.

However I noticed that the output file is named `temp-1.png` instead of `temp.png` what I would expect from reading table 1 in the standalone documentation. From there I get that the full name should be `\outname\outext`.

**My Question:** Is there a way to get the converted png file to be named `temp.png` without the added `-1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the documentation is somehow sparse on this, I found the option `multi` to control this. Simply set it to false and the output file will cease to be numbered.

```
\documentclass[tikz, multi=false, convert={ghostscript}]{standalone}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikz}
    \node {Test};
\end{tikz}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, you can accept own answer :-)